# mysql order by field row display even if empty

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-order-by, inner-join

I've two tables( bom and bom_parts). Need to inner join and display `stock_deduct,GRN_id,part_id` fields.

Table 1 (bom):

[image]

Table 2 (bom_parts):

[image]

MySql query:

```sql
SELECT 
    bom_part.stock_deduct,
    bom_part.GRN_id,
    bom.part_id 
FROM 
    bom 
    INNER JOIN 
    bom_part 
        ON bom_part.BOM_id=bom.id  
WHERE 
    batch_id='0' AND
    `sr_no`=23 
ORDER BY 
    FIELD(part_id, 34,8,36,6)
```

Query Result:

[image]

**Expected Result:**

**Even if the `part_id` field is empty in this case `8, 6`, I just want to display the part_id with the stock_deduct field as 1 in the result** as mentioned below.

| Stock_deduct | GRN_id | part_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 34 |
| 2 | 9 | 34 |
| 3 | GRN1 | 34 |
| **1** |  | **8** |
| 1 | GRN3 | 36 |
| 2 | GRN2 | 36 |
| **1** |  | **6** |

As you can see the row 4 and 7 in the expected result table as the specified `ORDER BY FIELD(part_id, 34,8,36,6)` order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use left join you will get also those elements that doesn' have a matching id on the other side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`, and filtering:

```
select coalesce(bp.stock_deduct, 1) as stock_deduct, bp.grn_id, b.part_id 
from bom b
left join bom_part bp on bp.bom_id = b.id  
where b.batch_id = 0 and b.sr_no = 23 and b.part_id in (34, 8, 36, 6)
order by field(part_id, 34, 8, 36, 6)
```

The filter on `bom.part_id` in the `where` clause brings the relevent row of `bom`. The we bring the parts table with a `left join`, so unmatched boms are not filtered out. Finally, `coalesce()` turns missing `stock_deduct` to `1`.

Comment: Is it possible to display a row if a part_id is not present in bom table? For Example: `in (34, 8, 36, 6, 78)` - The part_id 78 is not present in both tables. Can we use  the same approach to display as new row  `1 NULL 78`  ?

Comment: @ubs0305: no, this query does not add missing rows to the resultset. You would need additional logic for that (such as moving the values to a derived table).

Comment: Can you post a rough structure how to do that if possible for you?

Comment: @ubs0305: comments are not meant for such interaction. I would recommend asking *a new question* for this.

Comment: Sure. I'll post a new question.

Comment: New question link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506927/mysql-display-as-new-row-if-part-id-is-not-present